# Hello world in VBS

Tags: vba, vbscript, window

I have start playing with VBScript a couple of days ago and there is a problem that is irritating me. I have tried to test simple hello world program:

```
Module Hello
  Sub Main()
      MsgBox("Hello, World!") ' Display message on computer screen.
  End Sub 
End Module
```

When I run it with `cscript "hello world.vbs"`, from cmd. I'm getting an error: 
`M:\hello world.vbs(6, 1) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected statement`

When I change code to only: 
`MsgBox("Hello, World!") ' Display message on computer screen.`
Code is running normally. There is a popup message and there are no errors.
I'm using Win 7 SP1, Sublime text 3 and I have installed .Net 4.5; 4.6.

I'm a bit noob to .VBS so please don't be harsh. Thank you xD.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The entry point for VBScript is the global area at the top of the script file.

You do not need to declare a containing structure like a `Module` and a `Main` function as an entry point.

Since it looks like you tried to adopt from Visual Basic (for Applications) I recommend [Visual Basic for Applications Features Not In VBScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30593abb(v=vs.84).aspx) as a reference.

Answer (score 7):

Use only this

```
Sub Main()
      MsgBox("Hello, World!") ' Display message on computer screen.
 End Sub
```

if you want to use with function

```
function Main()
         MsgBox("Hello, World!") ' Display message on computer screen.
end function
```

call with either the function or subroutine name in both cases to invoke it.

```
call Main
```